# Working with random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I'm trying to get my head around these two expressions

1.$\quad\displaystyle\,X_n\leq X_{n+1}$

2.$\quad\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n=X$

Since the variables take random values the only way for 1. to make sense
is $\mathbb{P}(X_n-X_{n+1}\leq 0 )=1$, isn't it?
Similarly, in what sense is the limit in point 2. intended (for example in the definition of almost sure convergence)? Not pointwise, for the realizations $x_n$ and $x$ change each time, according to their respective probability density functions...

Comment: yes, of course. Sorry for the typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A random variable is a function defined on a probability space $\Omega$, so it makes sense to ask that the inequality hold for all $\omega \in \Omega$.

$X_n \leq X_{n+1}$ means $\forall \, \omega\in \Omega, \ X_n(\omega) \leq X_{n+1}(\omega)$. Same for the limit.

Now you are correct that we often only need the inequality to hold for almost all $\omega\in \Omega$, in which case it amounts to what you have written. The set of $\omega \in \Omega$ for which the inequality holds is of probability one. Cautious writers will write it
$$X_n \leq X_{n+1} \hbox{ almost everywhere }$$
or $$X_n \leq X_{n+1} \hbox{ a.e.}$$
But often, as an abuse of notation, the term $a.e.$ is dropped. In many probability books, there is  a short paragraph at the beginning saying that inequalities should be understood almost everywhere unless stated otherwise.